# Operating System Development Toolkit

Tags: operating-system, x86, x86-64, toolkit

I want to get into OS development. However, I'm not interested in all the quirks with the x86 architecture. I'm interested in the *design* of the OS.

So I looked around for an (x86, or x86_64 would be even better) OS toolkit. Something that deals with switching to protected mode and configuring interrupts through simple C function calls.

The only thing that I was able to find was [this](http://www.cs.utah.edu/flux/oskit/) toolkit that hasn't been touched since 2002. Before I get started with my OS, I wanted to make sure that there isn't a more recent/better toolkit to aid in OS development (for x86 or x86-64). So, **is there a better toolkit than this, and if I use these kinds of toolkits, what kinds of problems might I encounter along the road** (that I wouldn't have run into had I done all the gritty work myself)?

Comment: What is your goal here? To learn how to build an operating system?  Building an OS while not wanting to deal with the particulars of the hardware seems like a bit of a contradiction to me on the face of it. To clarify, I'm not trying to be discouraging, just wondering what your underlying goal is, and whether there might be a better project than building an OS that fulfills it.

Comment: @Viny Pai: My goal here is more to design the systems that deal with how programs interact with eachother and then write all the lower level programs like network drivers and UI systems that I wouldn't normally be able to mess with in most operating systems.

Comment: why not just fiddle with reactos or a linux disto in that case?

Comment: @Necrolis: Although I haven't looked into either option very much, although I had thought about basing it off the linux kernel. But I figured that I would have to spend so much time peeling away everything I didn't want that it wouldn't be worth it. I still want to make my own scheduler and all that stuff. I just don't want to have to learn x86 assembly, it's too ugly.

Answer (score 2):

There are no (good) OS toolkits; and I'm not sure a good OS toolkit would make any practical sense (e.g. it'd need to cover all possible OS designs rather than just one, and would be more complex than any single OS could ever be).

The good news is that you probably don't need a toolkit anyway. If you aren't planning to write your own boot code (e.g start with GRUB), then the amount of assembly you need isn't very much and most of it can be taken from elsewhere fairly easily (e.g. http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples).

I probably shouldn't tell you the bad news; but a scheduler is a small part of a kernel, and a kernel is a small part of an OS. For example, a scheduler might be 2000 lines of code, but Linux is about 50 million lines of code, and if you add stuff like Apache, X, Gnome/KDE, Mozilla, etc on top of that then you can imagine how much potential for "gritty work" might be involved in an entire OS... :-)